# troubleshooting hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop-yarn, iptables

I am trying to setup a 3-workers 1 master hadoop cluster using 2.7.1. When I start the cluster, the master has the following daemons running:

```
2792 NameNode 
3611 NodeManager 
4362 Jps 
3346 ResourceManager 
2962 DataNode 
3169 SecondaryNameNode
```

And in the three worker nodes,

```
2163 NodeManager
2030 DataNode
2303 Jps
```

Problem is when I look at the web UI, the cluster does not recognize the 3 workers. It says 1 live data node and that is the master itself. Please have a look here:

[http://master:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLPKC.png)

Question is, what are the daemon processes that are suppose to be running on workers node? I tried to look at the log files and didnt find anything helpful because it contains log only related to running daemons and the log files does not have any errors or Fatal errors.

I thought secondary namenode should be running in workers and ports are not letting it to communicate. So I tried to open up Port 9000 and 9001 in master by

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000  -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9001  -j ACCEPT
iptables-save
```

but this didnt help much. Still facing the same problem. Log files in workers are not helpful either.

Appreicate your help in fixing this.

Edit 1:

The following is my configuration at core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9001</value> <!-- slave1, 2 & 3 in position of master -->
    </property>
</configuration>
```

This is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost math2
127.0.1.1 math2

192.168.1.2 master
192.168.1.3 worker1
192.168.1.7 worker5
192.168.1.8 worker6
```

This is my configuration at /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


    address 192.168.1.2 (3,5,6 instead of 2 for slaves)
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Here is the log output for one of the datanodes:

```
2016-02-05 17:54:12,655 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:50010] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

Comment: Did you configure all nodes on your cluster? Is fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml set on all nodes?

Restart a datanode on one of your slave nodes and look if any exceptions show up

Comment: How you configured your slave machine..Did you copied every folder(hadoop) and config files from master to slaves...?

Comment: @facha : Tried your approach but didnt work

Comment: @Krishna : Yes. I have setup a multi node cluster before and dont know what I did wrong this time.

Comment: can you post datanodes logs

Comment: @Krishna : posted already - do have a look

Comment: I think it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467568/hadoop-2-5-0-failed-to-start-datanode and https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202006456-Datanode-Exception-Cannot-start-secure-cluster-without-privileged-resources

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the ip-address of all the nodes in `/etc/hosts`. The `/etc/hosts` file of all nodes(master and slaves) should contain the ip-address of all the nodes in your cluster.
For example if we have three data nodes and a master node the `/etc/hosts` file should be:

```
192.168.0.1  master
192.168.0.2  datanode1
192.168.0.3  datanode2
192.168.0.4  datanode33
```

Comment: Did you disable the IPv6 in all nodes? If IPv6 is enable by default in your Linux distribution then it may also cause the problems.

Answer (score 0):

On Datanode you can see below process when you run jps command

19728 DataNode
19819 Jps

and when you run ps -aef |grep -i datanode on Datanode, it should show the two process one with root user and another with HDFS user